# JavaScript for submitting a form that redirects based on multiple variables

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, redirect

I'm sure this is just me missing something completely obvious, but I've been sitting here for a couple hours finagling, and have still come up with no dice. An amended version of my form that I'm going to use is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript;" type="text/javascript">
    function setAction() {
        var country = document.getElementById("FormCtrl_1").value;
        var business = document.getElementById("FormCtrl_2").value;
        if (country === "Afghanistan" && business === "Yes") {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="row"> <label for="FormCtrl_1">Where are you going?</label>
        <select id="FormCtrl_1" name="FormCtrl_1">
          <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
          <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Is this a business trip?</legend>
          <span>
            <input value="Yes" id="FormCtrl_2_1" name="FormCtrl_2" type="radio">
            <label for="FormCtrl_2_1">Yes</label></span>
            <span>
              <input value="No" id="FormCtrl_2_2" name="FormCtrl_2" type="radio">
              <label for="FormCtrl_2_2">No</label>
            </span>
          </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input value="Submit" onclick="setAction()" type="button">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a mash-up of a couple different iterations of looking through other question and answers, so it's entirely possible that at one point I was a lot closer than I am now, but it has all just started to look like gibberish to me, so I'm saying "uncle" and asking you wonderful people. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll need you to state your question?

Comment: Why does it not seem to be working? I'm trying to get an if statement that will redirect users to another page (placeholder is google) if they choose both Afghanistan and Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.onclick` event from the submit button and instead use the `.onsubmit` event on the form element. Like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return setAction()" method="post" action="">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="FormCtrl_1">Where are you going?</label>
    <select id="FormCtrl_1" name="FormCtrl_1">
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
      <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Is this a business trip?</legend>
      <span>
        <input value="Yes" id="FormCtrl_2_1" name="FormCtrl_2" type="radio">
        <label for="FormCtrl_2_1">Yes</label>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input value="No" id="FormCtrl_2_2" name="FormCtrl_2" type="radio">
        <label for="FormCtrl_2_2">No</label>
      </span>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Your JavaScript also has a few issue in it. The first issue is you're getting a value for a radio input that always has a value of "Yes", instead we need to check if it's checked(selected). The next issue is you need to return false so that the form is prevented from submitting and the page doesn't reload. Give this a try:

```
function setAction() {
    var country = document.getElementById("FormCtrl_1").value;
    var business = document.getElementById("FormCtrl_2_1").checked;

    if (country === "Afghanistan" && business === true) {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }

    return false;
}
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eF2wH/2/

*JSFiddle Note: The redirect will not work unless you use a URL other than Google*

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple that I was just missing because I stared at it for way too long. Works like a charm